# timer stop when browser tab is inactive or minimize

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I want to stop timer when browser tab is inactive or minimize but the issue is
when I change browser tab or minimize and after maximize browser tab, count of timer display two time in the window body. Kindly suggest the solution

```
var window_focus;    
$(window).focus(function() {
    window_focus = true;
    startCount();
});
$(window).blur(function() {
    window_focus = false;
    stopCount(); 
});
var c = 0;
var t;
var timer_is_on = 0;

function timedCount()
{
    c = c+1;
    t = setTimeout(function(){timedCount()},1000);    
}

function startCount()
{
    if (!timer_is_on)
    {
        timer_is_on=1;
        timedCount();
    }
}

function stopCount()
{
    clearTimeout(t);
    timer_is_on=0; 
    $('body').append('count' + c + '<br>');        
}
```

Comment: Your best bet will be HMTL5's [Page Visibility API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active). It is still expirimental.

Comment: are you using same script.. the newly opened tab.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this ?

Comment: yes udaykiran pulipati i m using same code see in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JWxS6/59/

Comment: jsfiddle link jsfiddle.net/JWxS6/59

Answer (score 6):

The only reliable way to do so is to use [Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API) offered by HTML5, it offers various ways to check browser visibility status.

for ex:

```
document.hidden // Returns true if the page is hidden
```

and

```
document.visibilityState // Returns a string telling state of visibility
```

also you can add listener on change of browser visibility states as follows :

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  console.log(document.hidden, document.visibilityState);
}, false);
```

but this does not work in all browsers, so you need to test this in multiple browsers before starting on this.